# UPDATE PreparedStatement not updating MSSQL using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to update a MSSQL instance using JDBC using a prepared statement, I made a method to update any record in the table when given the column name, the value to update, and the updated value.

```
public void updateProjectOptions(int projectID, int number, String column){
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE cryptic.dbo.projects SET ? = ? WHERE project_id = ?");
        int newNum = number+1;
        System.out.println(projectID+" "+newNum+" "+column);
        ps.setString(1, column);
        ps.setInt(2, newNum);
        ps.setInt(3, projectID);
        int debug = ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Rows affected: "+debug);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The first print statement is printing out the correct values so I know the inputs are correct, and the second print statement is letting me know that 1 row is affected which is correct.

If I run the script inside of Management Studio the script runs fine and updates the table, but if I run the script from the java project nothing is updated and no errors are generated.

The db table in question has 4 columns: (int)project_id, (nvarchar)project_name, (int)num_bugs, (int)num_features

Can anyone help me out with getting this to work and/or spot whats wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't query be SET COLUMN_NAME = ?....

Comment: @Nambari is right. You should have gotten an error with your SQL statement. You cannot pass a column (or table) name as a parameter.

Comment: Also, best to close your prepared statement, preferably in a ``finally`` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names cannot be parameterized in prepared statements. You can parameterize only literal values like strings or numbers.

Comment: Ahh... that makes sense, would have figured there would've been an SQL error thrown but thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a column name that way, only variables.

I would recommend that you close that `PreparedStatement` in method scope in a `finally` block.  Your way is asking for trouble.

I would also call writing to `System.out` a very bad idea.  I'd prefer returning the number of affected rows to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I would've marked your answer as accepted answer but you were just beat out by 1 min.

As a side note I was just using the SOP as debugging tests and will not be using them in production.

Comment: No worries, I don't need the rep.  You can still upvote it if you wish.  I would still write correct code - first we make our habits, then our habits make us.